# JQuery Plugin Multiple-Select - How-to ask if selectAll is checked without listeners

Tags: jquery, multiple-select

I have two Multiple-Select Plugins on one HTML Site from 
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/

I want to ask if the Checkbox SelectAll is checked without using a listener (i.e. to set a variable) because I am in another context:

The HTML-Code is this:

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tailoring Groups:</td>
                    <td><select id="cbTailoringGroups" multiple="multiple"></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Keypoint responsibility:</td>
                    <td><select id="cbRoles" multiple="multiple"></select></td>
                </tr>                
            </table>
```

I already tried this piece of code but it isn't working like expected...

```
if (!$("#cbTailoringGroups > input[data-name='selectAll']").is(':checked')) {}
```

According to chrome developer tools the problem could be, that the generated code looks like this:

[image: Generated Code by the jquery plugin]

What is the right way to ask if the checkbox "Select All" is checked? By the way: I have two instances on the HTML site so I can not simply ask for:

```
   $("input[data-name='selectAll']").is(":checked");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isAllChecked(parentId)
{
   return $("#" + parentId +" ~ div.ms-parent div.ms-drop ul li input[data-name='selectAll']").is(':checked');
}

console.log(isAllChecked('cbTailoringGroups'));
console.log(isAllChecked('cbRoles'));
```

Comment: @Archer It' s clear that the checkbox is not a child of cbTailoringGroups. I use "~" which means "next".

Comment: Sorry - you're right. I was thinking the ~ was the next child element, not the next sibling element. Nothing to see here :)

Comment: You could add the comment to your answer to explain the code. Now you just have a "code only answer".